# How to merge conflicts before a pull request? git pull already up to date

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working on a branch named feature/zd1234
I am creating a pull request so merge this branch with staging
In BitBucket I created the request and there are are couple of conflicts showing when I click the Diff tab
So I did

-`git pull git pull origin feature/zd1234`

which gave me

```
From bitbucket.org:example/example
 * branch              feature/1234 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

How can I resolve the conflict if I'm already up to date? Please explain like I'm 5 how to do this and where I'm going wrong.
It's not my own repo so I'm nervous about doing anything I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the conflict of with the branch you're merging into.

Try:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

(if your target branch is master)